# Factoring large numbers into triplets

Tags: algorithm, math

I've found similar questions but this is a bit more complicated.

I have a large number n(I actually have more, but it doesn't matter now), (>40 digits), and I want to find a*b*c=n triplets. n's prime factorisation is done. It has no large prime divisors, but many of small prime divisors. The sum of all prime divisors (included multiple divisors) is greater than 50.

I'd like to find a*b*c=n triplets, where a<=b<=c. I don't want all the triplets, because there are too much of them. I'm searching for special ones.

For example:

- the triplet(s) where c-a is minimal,
- the triplet(s) where c/a minimal,
- the one where a,b and c has the maximal common divisor,
- these conditions combined.

This can be a little easier to solve if we know that n=k!(factorial). Solving could lead to a general method.
Computing all these triplets with brute force is not an option because of the size of n, so i need a good algorithm or some special tools to help me implement a solution for this.

Sorry for my bad English,

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Are `a,b,c` prime factors? Do you receive a list of prime factors as input?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! We know the prime divisors. This is why I'm preferring k! numbers to work with: these numbers prime factorisation is very simple. But the number of all distinct divisors is too high to check them with loops. For 40!, |D|~ 10^8. Don't forget, these are big numbers, working with them is pretty time consuming.

Comment: So `a, b, c` are just factors, not necessarily prime?

Comment: Yes, they are just factors. If they were primes, they would be the given prime divisors of n, so we had nothing to do. In the k! case they are probably neither relatively primes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have the solution, but I have no time to implement it today. I write it down, so maybe somebody will agree with me or will spot the weak point of my algorithm.

So let's see the first or second case, where c/a or c-a should be minimal.

1: In first step I split the prime factors of n to 3 group with a greedy algorithm. 
I will have an initial a,b and c and they will be not very far from each other. The prime factors will be stored in 3 arrays: a_pf,b_pf,c_pf.

2: In next step I compute all the possible factors for a,b and c, I store them in different arrays, then I order these arrays. These will be a_all,b_all and c_all.

3: I compute q=max(a,b,c)/min(a,b,c). (now we can say that a is the smallest, c is the greatest number)

4: I search a_all and c_all for numbers on this condiition: c_all[i]/a_all[j] < q. When I find it, I change the prime factors of these values in a_pf and c_pf. With this method, the largest and the smallest member of the triplet will come closer to each other.

I repeat step 2-3-4, until I can. I think this will end after finite number of steps.

Since the triplet's members are smaller than the original n, I hope this solution will give me the correct triplet at most in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with a simple, `O(|D|^2)` algorithms, where `D` is an ordered list of all the numbers dividing `n`, which you already have.

Note that you only have to find `a,b`, because `c=n/(a*b)`, so the problems boils down to finding all the pairs `(a,b)` in `D` so that `a<b` and `n/(a*b) ∈ D`.

Pseudocode:

```
result = empty_list
for (int i=0; i<D.size-1, i++) {          // O(|D|)
    for (j=i+1; j<D.size, j++) {          // O(|D|)
         a, b = D[i], D[j]
         c = n/(a*b)
         if (D.contains(c) && c>b) {      // O(1)
             result.append( (a,b,c) )
         }
    }
}                                         // O(|D|)*O(|D|)=O(|D|^2)
```

Comment: So you're basically saying that the questioner is mistaken to say, "Computing all these triplets with brute force is not an option because of the size of `n`"? This seems plausible, but the questioner only gives a lower bound on the number of prime factors (50), not an upper bound ;-)

Comment: True, but the number of factors is `O(log n)`, which is roughly the number of digits of `N`. Can't be very high if `N` has 40 digits. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179353/effective-upper-bound-for-the-number-of-prime-divisors

Comment: the number of prime factors is `O(log n)`, the number of distinct factors `|D|` is some combinatoric operation bigger than that.

Comment: The question doesn't say there's already a list of all factors. It says "n's prime factorisation is done". Getting a list of all factors of `k!` is again a combinatoric operation -- not particularly difficult but might be time-consuming.

Comment: I've assumed that the list of prime divisors is given as input. If not, it's a question about factorization, not about triplets.

Comment: You don't seem to be distinguishing between having prime factors and having all factors. Of course you can work out the latter from the former, but the two sets are not necessarily of comparable size (and for factorials, they aren't of comparable size, the set of all factors is far larger).

Comment: Yes, all factors can be computed from prime factors. So we can say, we have all the distinct factors of n. As I said, for 40!, the number of all distinct divisors of n is about 10e8, while the number of prime factors is about 80(included multiple prime factors).
But I'm not sure we have to find all the distinct factors to solve this problem. There might be a way to build a,b and c using only the prime factors.